# CSS Bootstrap Vertical Alignment - 3 Column

Tags: css, flexbox, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have 3 columns with 3 different titles, some being longer and taking up more space, but I want to start my paragraphs in the same place. The headings should be a consistent height, regardless of the amount of text.

I can use a minimum height for each title, but I think there is another way to align the paragraphs and make them go the same way.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9yrd.png)

[What i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imNkp.png)

https://jsfiddle.net/rxsok1jm/

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4">
              <h2 class="">
                <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>Retrouvez qui vous appelle !
                 </h2>
              <p class="">Vous avez reçu un appel inconnu et vous ne connaissez pas l’identité du propriétaire ? Ce numéro est-il nuisible ou est-ce vraiment quelqu’un qui souhaite vous joindre ? Trouvez les informations concernant le numéro de téléphone pour vous
                faire un avis.
                <br> </p>
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary">En savoir plus</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4">
              <h2 class="">
                <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>Faites vous un avis sur chaque numéro inconnu.
                <br> </h2>
              <p class="">La communauté Infos-numero.com est là pour vous aider, grâce aux différents avis, à vous faire une idée concernant un numéro de téléphone inconnu et de déterminer si votre interlocuteur est nuisible ou fiable.
                <br> </p>
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary">En savoir plus</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4">
              <h2 class="">
                <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>Racontez nous votre experience.
                <br> </h2>
              <p class="">N’hésitez pas à partager votre expérience téléphonique, qu’elle soit positive ou négative. Partager des avis aide notre communauté à se faire un avis plus précis sur les réelles intentions de votre interlocuteur.
                <br> </p>
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary">En savoir plus</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: show your code not pic

Comment: yeap :) code added

Comment: does this help? `.col-md-12
{
margin-left: 20%;
}
p
{
  width: 50%;
}
.btn
{
  margin-left: -100%
}`

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap you can use this class in column:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4>Your paraghraph</div>
```

Comment: Yes but i want all paragraph starting at the same line but title have differents lines

Comment: Yeah, understood so try this: max-width:200px; word-wrap:break-word; in your title class, or your h2 directly in your case